# Floating right doesn't work on 404 pages only...?

Tags: css

I am setting up a custom header and footer for a client's site which you can view here:

http://gag5.rhinomarketinggroup.com/

The social media links float right just fine here...and on all pages. But for some reason on the 404 pages they do not float to the right. Very confused. Can't seem to find a reason why it would change on the 404 pages.

Example 404 page:

http://gag5.rhinomarketinggroup.com/404

clarifying images:

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBGiK.png)[image][image]

Comment: Its the problem with this div `<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_2  et_pb_column_1">` Just add float to this div and everything will be fine with the header.

Answer (score 1):

On the normal page, you have the following CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 981px)
.et_pb_gutters3 .et_pb_column_1_2, .et_pb_gutters3.et_pb_row .et_pb_column_1_2 {
    width: 47.25%;
}
```

Which is applied to `.et_pb_gutters3` (The part where the LinkedIn icon is)

You also have:

```
@media (min-width: 981px)
.et_pb_gutters3 .et_pb_column, .et_pb_gutters3.et_pb_row .et_pb_column {
    margin-right: 5.5%;
}
```

Which is applied to `.et_pb_column` (The part where the logo is)

I'd suggest you add this code to the 404 pages as well.

**UPDATE:**

Though it seems as if this does not completely solve the problem. The easy way to fix this is to add `float:right`; to the `.et_pb_column_1` (The second half, containing the LinkedIn icon)

Answer (score 1):

```
.et_pb_column.et_pb_column_1_2.et_pb_column_1 {
 float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution to Header:**

Change `<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_2 et_pb_column_1">` to `<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_2 et_pb_column_1" style="float:right">` (Line no. 202)

**Problem with Footer:**

You have used `et_pb_column_1_3` and `et_pb_column_2_3` classes in 404 page, while you have used `et_pb_column_1_2` classes in normal pages.

**Solution to Footer:**

Replace `et_pb_column_1_3` and `et_pb_column_2_3` classes with `et_pb_column_1_2` in the footer. (Line no. 366 and 384)

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem because of @media rule

if you inspect `<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_2  et_pb_column_1">`
you have apply following media rule on it:

```
@media (min-width: 981px)
.et_pb_gutters3 .et_pb_column_1_2, .et_pb_gutters3.et_pb_row .et_pb_column_1_2 {
    width: 47.25%;
}
```

but on 404 page it is not applying @media rule

Solution: Apply @media rule on 404 page